# DELETE 404 (Not found) error when using axios.delete

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I am trying to send a delete request with axios using the following code:

```
   const handleDelete = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.delete(`https://tinderclonepmish.herokuapp.com/delete/${userId}`)
            if (response.status === 200) console.log('response success ')
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message)
        }
    }
```

handleDelete is being triggered by the code:

```
<button onClick={handleDelete}>DELETE ACCOUNT</button>
```

and trying to access in the backend with the following code:

```
app.delete('/delete/:userId', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.userId)
})
```

however, I am getting the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5wwC.png).

In the same file as the handleDelete() I have also made a put request which works with no issues :

```
 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {   
            const response = await axios.put('https://tinderclonepmish.herokuapp.com/user', {formData})
            if (response.status === 200) navigate('/dashboard')
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message)
        }
    }
```

with the backend for the put request being:

```
app.put('/user', async (req, res) => {
    const client = new MongoClient(uri)
    const formData = req.body.formData

    try {
        await client.connect()
        const database = client.db('app-data')
        const users = database.collection('users')

        const query = {user_id: formData.user_id}
        const updateDocument = {
            $set: {
                first_name: formData.first_name,
                dob_day: formData.dob_day,
                dob_month: formData.dob_month,
                dob_year: formData.dob_year,
                show_gender: formData.show_gender,
                gender_identity: formData.gender_identity,
                gender_interest: formData.gender_interest,
                url: formData.url,
                about: formData.about,
                matches: formData.matches
            },
        }
        const insertedUser = await users.updateOne(query, updateDocument)
        res.send(insertedUser)
    } finally {
        await client.close()  //ensures client will close when finished or error occurs
    }
})
```

Appreciate the help

Comment: The error says that there is no route found. Are you sure about the url ?

Comment: What are the route definition you are having?

Comment: what is the type of user_id?

Comment: @TobokSitanggang question, userId is a string.

Comment: @Johan the url worked for other requests, so I assumed that it would work for delete as well, the only thing changed is that the userId is being passed through.

Comment: @CodeThing, i'm not sure what you mean by route definition?

Comment: @EdrisElbow What i mean is the place where you define you routes in the backend like... app.get(), app.put(), app.delete()

Comment: @CodeThing the app.delete in the backend is posted above, along with the working app.put route. Is that what you meant?

Comment: are you sure that you have `user_id` in user model instead of default index `_id`?